# numpy .reshape function changes array element type

Tags: python, numpy

How can you use the numpy .reshape function on an Array without changing the Array element type in the process? Here is what I mean:

```
letters = ['A', 'B', 'C']
letters_array = np.array(letters)
print letters_array
#['A' 'B' 'C']
print type(letters_array[0])
#<type 'numpy.string_'>
```

now, I use .reshape

```
letters_array = letters_array.reshape(3, 1)
print letters_array
#[['A']
#['B']
#['C']]
print type(letters_array[0])
#<type 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

Why does the element type change from a string to an array after using .reshape and how can one keep the same data type?

Comment: reshape returns a ndarray, this is documented and expected behaviour, it wouldn't make sense to be able to reshape from a 1-D array to a N-D array without changing the type see: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html. the element type should be unchanged though

Comment: I have read the docs, if you read my question properly, I am asking why the elements of the reshaped Array is also an Array and not a string

Comment: I think you are confusing how to index into a ndarray, if you do `print type(letters_array[0][0])` then it shows the element type is still `<class 'numpy.str_'>`

Comment: yes, I know that. The question is why is an element converted from a string to an array in the first place

Answer (score 4):

First the `letters_array` has only one dimension, so when you index it as `letters_array[0]` you get a single element.

```
letters = ['A', 'B', 'C']
letters_array = np.array(letters)
print letters_array.ndim
# 1
```

After the `reshape` the array has two dimensions, meaning indexing in the same way gives you a row of the array (which has type `numpy.ndarray`). To get a single element you have to supply one index for each dimension:

```
letters_array = letters_array.reshape(3, 1)
print letters_array.ndim
# 2
print type(letters_array[0, 0])
# <type 'numpy.string_'>
```

Note that the element type is the same on both occasions! Instead of using `type` it's better to look at the `dtype` property of the array, which is independent of array shape:

```
print letters_array.dtype
# |S1
```

Comment: I get that. But I dont get why is because the original array already of type ndarray. No where in the docs does it say that .reshape must return a ndim > 1

Comment: This is not a serious problem, I realized that indexing will get me back the string value. I am asking for the pure sake of understanding this function better.

Comment: @user1452494: `reshape` may return an array with `ndim` equal to one, but by supplying `(3, 1)` as argument you ask to return an array with two dimensions. It seems what you want is a column vector that has only one dimension, but such a thing doesn't exist in Numpy...